# Problemas para deletar dados da tabela com ::PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Alguém pode me explicar qual o erro ou se tem alguma falha no script??

Pelo que sei esta correto porem não funciona..
No script ele pegar o ID de quem seguio e o ID de quem foi seguido e deveria remover pelo parâmetros `WHERE` da linha **MYSQL**, porem não esta deletando..

```
// SISTEMA DE FOLLOW::USERS
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'func_follow') {
        $method     = $_POST['method'];
        $id_de  = $_POST['id_de'];
        $id_para    = $_POST['id_para'];
        $f_data     = time();

        if($method == 'remove'){
            $busca_dados_s = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `lc_follow` WHERE `f_de` = ? AND `f_para` = ?");
            $busca_dados_s->execute(array($id_de, $id_para));
            if($busca_dados_s->rowCount() > 0){
                $lc_unfollow_dados = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `lc_follow` WHERE `f_de`=:f_de AND `f_para`=:f_para)");
                $lc_unfollow_dados->bindValue(":f_de",$id_de);
                $lc_unfollow_dados->bindValue(":f_para",$id_para);
                $lc_unfollow_dados->execute();

                if($lc_unfollow_dados){
                    echo    '<div class="but_add" onclick="functionAjax_follow(\''.$id_de.'\', \''.$id_para.'\',\'add\')">
                                Seguir
                            </div>';
                } else {
                    echo '::ERRO::';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: É a [mesma questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112448/91)?

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar prepared statements não é necessario escapar os valores com aspas simples:

```
DELETE FROM `lc_follow` WHERE `f_de`=':f_de' AND `f_para`=':f_para'
   ----------------------------------^     ^              ^       ^
```

Comment: antes estavam sem, porem tbm não esta funcionando...

Comment: @PedroQuezado, adicione isso para ver o erro, `if(!$lc_unfollow_dados->execute()){ print_r($lc_unfollow_dados->errorInfo());}`

Comment: Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 )  -- Esse foi o retorno

Comment: @PedroQuezado remova o `)` no final do delete. `f_para=:f_para)"`

Comment: OHH sabe explicar o porque que quando eu executo esse código ele INSERE duas vezes o mesmo valor na tabela?? 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/7wwCa.png  @rray